# Can the Silvery Barbs spell be cast on a target more than once as a reaction to the same roll?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, stacking, reactions, simultaneous-effects

**Can the silvery barbs spell spell be cast on a target more than once as a reaction to the same roll?**

For example, say you have two wizards fighting one creature. The enemy passes a saving throw against some other spell/ability. One wizard then casts silvery barbs on the enemy, forcing it to reroll the d20 and use the lower roll, but it still succeeds.
Can the other wizard then also cast silvery barbs on it to force yet another reroll? Or is that not possible as spell effects don't stack?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Multiple instances of *silvery barbs* can affect the same roll

I assume that when you say "it passes the save", you're referring to the reroll – that is, the creature successfully made a saving throw against some other effect, and then the reroll forced by the first *silvery barbs* spell is still not sufficient to make them fail the saving throw, and now the second wizard wants to cast *silvery barbs* to create a second reroll and possibly make them fail.

Here is the rule for [Combining Magical Effects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CombiningMagicalEffects) (PHB, p. 204) that you refer to when you mention spell effects not stacking:

> The effects of different spells add together **while the durations of those spells overlap**. The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine, however. Instead, the most potent effect—such as the highest bonus—from those castings applies while their durations overlap, or the most recent effect applies if the castings are equally potent and their durations overlap.

The duration of *silvery barbs* is instantaneous – that is, the spell does not create an ongoing effect – so there are no durations that could overlap to make the rule apply.

Consider two casters casting *fireball* on the same creature (let's say, one with a readied action to the other casting): you also would apply the damage from both, not only from the one that has the higher result, because they resolve in an instant.

Answer (score 6):

### Short Answer: Yes.

Long Answer: Yes.

The first wizards sees a goblin hit a warrior and per the reaction text *( * - which you take when a creature you can see within 60 feet of yourself succeeds on an attack roll, an ability check, or a saving throw)* can cast Silvery Barbs. The Wizard can give the boon to a character.

The goblin does a reroll and succeeds a second time.

The second wizard sees the goblin hit the warrior. Second wizard can cast Silvery Barbs. The goblin must reroll. However, the Second wizard <strike>must</strike> should choose to give the boon to a different character than the first wizard selected (otherwise it would be wasted).

NOTE: Silvery Barbs does not invoke any saving throws for anyone involved.

Comment: Technically, couldn’t the second wizard give the boon to the same character as the first, it would just be wasted (barring *dispel magic* or something)?

Comment: Great answer, you should also clarify regarding the "and it passes the save" comment as there is no save for Silvery Barbs.

Comment: When you say "the boon", I assume you're referring to the second paragraph of the spell description ("The chosen creature has advantage on the next attack roll, ability check, or saving throw it makes within 1 minute.")?

Comment: Are you saying that the second wizard is reacting to the successful reroll as if it was a new attack roll?  Or is it two simultaneous reactions to the initial roll?  I think it has to be the latter, but your answer presents it in a way that seems to hint at the former.